# How to reconstruct a marginal dataset into a regular pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a marginal table that looks like this. (3 rows x 87 columns)

```
    workclass  Government
    education  Bachelors+
    occupation Bin 3
    hours-per-
    week       <45
    capital-   
    gain       Capital Gain  Capital Loss  No Capital Gain ...
    
    income     
    -------------------------------------------------------
    <=50k       28             29            479
    >50k        72             32            265
    All         100            61            744
```

However, I want to reconstruct it into a regular dataframe like this.

```
       workclass  education    occupation  ... income
   ----------------------------------------------------
   0   Government Bachelors+   Bin 3       ...  <=50k
   1   Private    Bachelors+   Bin 1       ...  <=50k
   2   Private    No Bachelors Bin 3       ...  <=50k
```

I honestly don't know where to start. Just need some suggestions. I tried to do pd.melt(df) but the "income" column disappears (I am guessing it has to do with the fact that the index in the marginal table was "income") and instead a "value" column appears like this.

```
  workclass  education    occupation  ... value
  -----------------------------------------------
  Government Bachelors+   Bin 3       ...  26
  Private    Bachelors+   Bin 1       ...  70
  Private    No Bachelors Bin 3       ...  98
```

My result should be a dataframe I can eventually use to predict income with a logistic regression classifier.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: most likely a bunch of usntack and possibly melt. That said, please post a [mcve] as text. Images are _not_ reproducible.

Comment: @DjerroNeth pd.melt, pivot

Comment: @Manakin thank you for your comment! was unaware of that.